# how to convert hibernate query to criteria

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have already written a query looping through multiple entities and want to convert it to a detached criteria query. Not sure how to do it for multiple tables

```
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("from ");
    queryString.append(Entity).append(" e where e.specificationId in (:ids) 
       and not exists ( select 1 from Association a where "
           + "a.sourceReference = e.reference )").append("order by    
                e.displayOrder");
```

Comment: You can use Spring JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JPA.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<T extends Content<T>> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>

@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.specificationId in (?) and not exists ( select 1 from Association a where a.sourceReference = e.reference ) order by e.displayOrder", nativeQuery=true)
public void T findByIds(List<Long> ids);
```

You will create one interface for each type and implements GenericRepository.

Ex :

```
@Repository
public interface AbcRepository extends GenericRepository<Abc>{

}
```

Refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/